# ReadTimeout trying to connect to dynamodb-local in CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, amazon-dynamodb-local

I am trying to execute pytests that use dynamodb-local docker container in CodeBuild.
I figured out how to run docker in CodeBuild by setting Privileged mode to True.
The docker container gets built successfully and is running in the CodeBuild instance.
I keep getting a ReadTimeout error when I try to connect to dynamodb in the container.

I can `curl http://localhost:8000` and get the expected MissingAuthToken response.
But when I try to `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000/`, I get a ReadTimeout error.
And when I try to run my tests and create a table in the dynamodb-local container, I get the same ReadTimeout error.
I can run all my unit tests that don't use the container but I can't get past this timeout error.